# how to remove emty elements from tcl list

Tags: list, null, tcl

hi 
I have following list

> % set qprList {{{}} {{}} {{}} {{}}
>   {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}}
>   {{}} {{}} {{}} 12345 {{}} {{}} {{}}
>   {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}}
>   {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}}
>   {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}}
>   {{}} 12345 {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}}
>   {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}}
>   {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}}
>   {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} 12345
>   {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}}
>   {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}}
>   {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}}
>   {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} 12345 {{}} {{}}
>   {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}}
>   {{}} {{}}}

I want to remove all the elements which are empty. since list of list is i am not able to do it in single loop interation.

Any simple way to achieve this?

Comment: do you care about any of the list structure? i.e. do you want the whole list flattened? or just bits with leaves which are the empty string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no empty elements in that list.  The ones that seem empty can be considered as (a) a string "{}" or (b) a list with one element which is an empty string or an empty list.

```
package require struct::list
set non_empty [struct::list filter \
                 [struct::list flatten $qprList] \
                 {apply {{x} {expr {[string length $x] > 0}}}} \
              ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You might also try this:

```
set listwithoutnulls [lsearch -all -inline -not -exact $listwithnulls {}]
```

It doesn't require a package include. It, too, can be re-applied.

Answer (score 1):

Coming from the Tclers Wiki (http://wiki.tcl.tk/440):

> To flatten a list:
>
> `concat {*}$nested`
>
> It can be applied multiple times:
>
> `proc flatten data {
>       concat {*}$data
>   }`
>
> `set a {{a {b c}} {d {e f}}}  ; # {a {b c}} {d {e f}}
>   flatten $a                   ; # a {b c} d {e f}
>   flatten [flatten $a]         ; # a b c d e f`

Answer (score 0):

I also use struct::list because I am lazy:

```
package require struct::list
set non_empty [struct::list flatten -full $qprList]
```