# Remove null character tcl

Tags: list, tcl, empty-list, tclsh, regsub

I have a variable which is getting a suffix of {} for some reason. 
i.e echo $file

```
<path to file> {}
```

This variable when consumed in other commands is now erroring out. How do I remove this empty list that is getting appended to my variable?

Something like regsub {} $file {} file . But that doesn't seem to work

Comment: Might be better to find out why that empty list is there; what's causing it than trying to patch the result... Unless it's something out of your control in which case I guess you could treat the variable as a list and either take the 1st element of file or do a list replace? I can't guarantee it will work without more information

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259294/how-to-remove-emty-elements-from-tcl-list

Comment: Or you can use "set filtered_path [join [join $file]]". join will flatten the $file list leaving "<path_to_file> ", then a subsequent join will remove the space.

Comment: As Jerry recommends, better find and close the source of the artefact. For the time being, you may also clean the string using `string map {\{\} ""} $file`

Comment: Besides: This is simply an empty string, not a `null` character by whatever comparison.

Comment: While a `regsub` or `string map` could do it, working out why the problem is happening and stopping it from happening in the first place is the right approach. Better to fix the cause than patch over the symptom.

Answer (score 0):

regsub works just fine. Try below:

```
% set a "file name {}"
file name {}
% regsub -all -- "{}" $a "" x
1
% puts $x
file name
%
```